# Can a Black Hole be moved by lasers?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, black-holes, momentum, conservation-laws, laser

I've read that an object colliding with a black hole will move it, as it would any other object. Could a laser continuously fired into a black hole move it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A laser carries linear momentum, so when a laser is fired into a black hole, this linear momentum is transferred to the black hole, causing it to accelerate.

Of course, for a realistic astrophysical black hole you'd need an unrealistically powerful laser for this to make a significant impact on the motion of the black hole.

Comment: FWIW, the Sun's luminosity is $\approx 3.828×10^{26}$ watts. We can use $E=pc$ to calculate the light's momentum, and equate it to $p=mv$ for the change in momentum of the black hole (this ignores the small change in mass of the BH due to absorbing the light). If we blast a small 3 solar mass BH with the entire solar output for 1 million years, we increase its speed by ~6.75 m/s.

Comment: @PM2Ring That's actually...more than I was expecting, honestly.

Comment: Would a micro black hole be moved more or less?

Comment: You could fire the laser to just skim the hole such that the light did a 180 and came back at you. That would double the momentum transfer.

Comment: @Keith and then you could set up a mirror so that after the light does a 180 you can bounce it back and do it again, reusing the light an arbitrary number of times.  (Still not realistic.)